# Cannot find Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0 in startup.cs of MVC setup on .net 5

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-5

My ASP.NET Core MVC application with React front end and .NET Core backend ran fine when published through vs2019. But when I try to do the CICD way (build pipeline, release pipeline through vso tasks), I am getting the below in the event log from Azure Portal.

> CoreCLR Version: 5.0.921.35908
>
> .NET Version: 5.0.9
>
> Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>
> Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'. The system cannot find the file specified.
> File name: 'Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=92742159e12e44c8'
>
> at xxxxPortal.Program.<>c.b__1_0(HostBuilderContext context, IConfigurationBuilder config)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.BuildAppConfiguration()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at xxxxPortal.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\a\1\s\Odyssey Portal\xxxxPortal\Program.cs:line 16

My portal solution has a web app (react) project along with 4 others projects (.NET Core). They are controller/modal/repository/tests. All of them are setup to have .NET5 as the target.

In the Nuget restore task in VSO, I can see the dependency of Azure.Core are brought in from different projects. They range from 1.14 to 1.04. There is no presence of .NET Core 1.20.0

My portal project already setup with this

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
<PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>
```

How should I add to my solution/projects to fix this problem so my release pipeline can fix this "Azure.Core, Version=1.20.0.0 missing file" problem at runtime?

** Issue was due to there was another solution later on in the same pipeline having .net core 3.1 mix with .net framework.   To see this error show up in the build, I added a .net core 5 install in the build pipeline.

[final working pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sic2z.png)

Comment: It seems you maybe use the wrong type of task to restore/build .net core webapp.

Comment: Could you  show us the pipline/task in your devops page, you can update the screenshot in the origin post, and hide sensitive info.

Comment: I got passed the issue.    I am not sure exactly which part of the fix contributes to fix but I did 2 things.

1) install the .net core 5 SDK build in the build pipeline.

Right after I made this change, when I requeue the build pipeline, there was one solution that I was not aware of in the pipeline tossed up error on Azure.Core.    I took a closer look and that solution had a mix of 2 projects.  One has .net Framework and one has .net 3.1 core    I then disabled this solution and the error in event log in Azure.Core is gone (it has some other errors but I know what it is).